# Activity after OOM

Tags: android, exception, memory, android-activity

I have activity `A`. From `A` I'm starting activity `B`.
In activity `B` I'm using a lot of memory and sometimes I get `OOM`. I'm working to repair this, but in the meantime I'd like to show some info for users.

`OOM` in most cases doesn't crash my app. It just closes activity `B` and resumes `A`. Is it possible to detect from `A`, that `B` wasn't finished correctly?

I could go back to `A` from many others activities, not only from `B`.

I don't want to set some flags in `A` (`b_started`, `b_finished`, `b_sth`). I'd like clean and simple solution if exists one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you could do handle this in the following manner:

1) Whenever you are starting an activity, use **startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);**
here pass the request code which is unique for activity B.

2) Now, whenever activity B will be closed, you will get a callback in A at
**protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)**
here check if the request code is similar to the code you used to start activity B.

3) Your final problem, is to find out whether Activity B was successfully closed or not. You may use the resultCode for that. Set it to **Success**, when you are intentionally closing the activity, or else it wont be success.

I hope this helps!